# Change AngularJS const by selection value in HTML

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

i have problem.
I generated project by JHipster -> angular + html,
and there i have pagination with AngularJS value -> ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
i can change this value manualy in pagination.config, but it's not the point of this project.
I need to make selection options to display number of pages -> 10,25,50,100.

```
<select id="pageSizeSelect" onchange="self.location.href='/request?pageSize='+this.value">
   <option value="10"> 10 </option>
...
</select>
```

how can i change this ITEMS_PER_PAGE ? By Angular ? or Java backend ?

Comment: can you post the part of your JS where the cons is set?

Answer (score 0):

its just EXPORT const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10;
than in other .ts files its just imported :)